# Nextjs API request only works locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, google-sheets-api, vercel

I am trying write to google sheet using '[google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet)' via Next.js API route. It works perfectly fine when I am testing locally. I can see the data being updated in the google sheet. However, when I deploy it to Vercel, it doesn't work. The 'Functions' log from Vercel shows the following error message.

> Error authentication FetchError: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
> at ClientRequest. (/var/task/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)
> at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
> type: 'system',
> errno: 'ECONNRESET',
> code: 'ECONNRESET',
> config: {
> method: 'POST',
> url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
> data: {
> grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
> assertion: ....

Below is my code if that's any help.

```
export default async function addRowAPI(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      let doc;
      try {
        doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(process.env.SPREADSHEET_ID);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error at line 15:', error);
      }

      try {
        await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
          client_email: process.env.GOOGLE_SHEETS_CLIENT_EMAIL,
          private_key: (process.env.GOOGLE_SHEETS_PRIVATE_KEY || '').replace(
            /\\n/g,
            '\n'
          ),
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error authentication', error);
      }

      await doc.loadInfo(); 
      console.log(doc.title);

      const sheet = doc.sheetsByTitle['Test_Sheet']; 
      console.log(sheet.title);
      console.log('addRow Doc:', doc);

      const newRow = await sheet.addRow(req.body);
      

      res.status(201).send();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json(error);
    }
  } else if (req.method === 'GET') {
    res.status(200).json({ ping: 'pong' });
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have all the environment variables properly set in Vercel? It's complaining about an authentication error, which could indicate wrong/non-existing credentials.

Comment: @juliomalves you are right. I missed out to set up one of the env variables. It's working now. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the error complains about an authentication issue which indicates wrong/non-existing credentials. Double-check you have all the environment variables properly set in Vercel.